# How to fix the following error plotting?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to plot some data, my code is really simple, the idea is just to have two ranges that are the columns that I want to plot in order to achieve this I receive them with four inbox boxes as follow:

```
    first = InputBox("first range", "Enter first range")
    first1 = InputBox("second range", "Enter second range")
    two = InputBox("second range", "Enter second range")
    two1 = InputBox("second range", "Enter second range")
```

My complete code looks as follows:

```
Sub ALL()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim chrt As Chart

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        first = InputBox("first range", "Enter first range")
        first1 = InputBox("second range", "Enter second range")
        two = InputBox("second range", "Enter second range")
        two1 = InputBox("second range", "Enter second range")
        Set rng = .Range("first:first1,two:two1")
        .Shapes.AddChart
        Set objChrt = .ChartObjects(.ChartObjects.Count)
        Set chrt = objChrt.Chart

        With chrt
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .SetSourceData Source:=rng
            End With
        End With
End Sub
```

My code looks to work well but when I want to run it in a macros, and I enter the following range

```
A2
A4
B2
B4
```

In the corresponding boxes and I press enter, I get an error in the following line:

Set rng = .Range("first:first1,two:two1")

I cannot fix this error, I really appreciate any suggestion to overcome this situation, thanks any how.

Comment: change `.Range("first:first1,two:two1")` to `.Range(first & ":" & first1,two  & ":" & two1)`

Comment: Thanks for the support, let me check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is due to passing all the variables inside double quotes so they evaluate as string.

[image]

with slight change in InputBox you can select the whole range from sheet itself.

```
 Set rng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Test", Type:=8)
```

See this:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839468.aspx

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range

    first = "A2"
    first1 = "A4"
    two = "B2"
    two1 = "B4"

    '/Error
    Set rng = Range("first:first1,two:two1")

    '/Valid
     Set rng = Range(first & ":" & first1, two & ":" & two1)

     '/ Robust way
     Set rng = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Sample", Type:=8)

End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate the support let me verify this.